# CBPeripheralManager startAdvertising not working on OS X yosemite

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, ibeacon

does anyone notice any issues when using your mac (running OS X 10.10 yosemite DP 6) as an iBeacon? I tried several tools and I also developed it myself (using the CBPeripheralManager startAdvertising) but without any luck.

When running those apps (+ the the code I developed myself) on a mac running OS X 10.9 Mavericks, it works like a charm.

Is there anything specific required for OS X 10.10 yosemite or is this a bug?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** Radius Networks has confirmed this issue has shown up on subsequent pre-releases of Yosemite.  This OS veesion blocks sending an iBeacon transmission with the internal interface, but allows it with external interfaces.  So you can **add an external Bluetooth dongle like the GBU521 and transmission works again.**

<strike>It's gotta be a bug in the code or something specific to your machine.  We have tested our [MacBeacon OSX app](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/macbeacon/) on Yosemite and have not noticed any problems.</strike>

Comment: "Recent changes to OS X 10.10 Yosemite prevent proper operation of the MacBeacon software. We regret being unable to provide you access to the capabilities of this software and are continuing to explore options to enable operation for OS X 10.10 Yosemite users." from the link...

Comment: CBPeripheralManager startAdvertising works in Yosemite.

Comment: While `CBPeripheralManager startAdvertising` does work in general on Yosemite, it does not successfully transmit the byte sequence needed for the iBeacon layout.

Comment: If you add an external dongle like the GBU521, Yosemite will send an iBeacon transmission successfully.  It just does not work with the internal interface.

Comment: Confirmed, I forgot to mention that in my tests I did it with an external Bluetooth 4.0 (USB). Thanks David.

Answer (score 3):

In fact you can indeed advertise your Mac running Yosemite as an iBeacon with an external compatible Bluetooth 4.0 (USB).
I wrote a simple iBeacon transmitter for Yosemite written in Swift, look here https://updatemycode.com/2014/11/29/yosemite-as-an-ibeacon-swift/.

Comment: I can confirm this. I´m using a plugable bt4le dongle. The results are not as reliable as seen on Mavericks but it is indeed working. @mgigirey what kind of dongle are you using?

Comment: I own a GMYLE Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter. On the link above I added a section at the end for recommended Bluetooth dongles.

Answer (score 2):

This does seem to be a problem with Yosemite 10.10.  This is acknowledged now on the radius network website: http://www.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/macbeacon/

I'm having to buy usb beacons that I can easily power on and off for testing because of this issue.

Comment: Correct.  This issue showed up on subsequent pre-releases of Yosemite.  We have reported it to Apple, but it is unclear if or when a fix will be available.

Comment: @davidgyoung do you have an openRdar ID?

Comment: The bug is not publicly visible on https://bugreport.apple.com, but it is submitted at Problem id 18468983 "Unable to broadcast a BLE Peripheral"

Comment: If you want, copy it to http://openradar.appspot.com then we can simply file duplicates to create awareness.

Comment: In Yosemite 10.10) this is not an issue.  I can confirm that CBPeripheralManager startAdvertising is working.

Comment: Works with external Bluetooth 4.0 (USB).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this with 10.10, but I'm able to use 10.11.3 to advertise as a beacon (at least with the project from @mgigirey). Perhaps Apple opened this again?