# how to broadcast Yosemite os as beacon?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I am trying to broadcast my Yosemite OS as a beacon but i am not able to broadcast. i did not get any error but it doest not work. i have referred this link https://github.com/mgigirey/iBeaconSwiftOSX. BLE is also supported. is there any way to make mac os as a beacon?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    self.manager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

    [self.uuidFieldCell setStringValue:@"B0702880-A295-A8AB-F734-031A98A512DE"];
    [self.majorFieldCell setStringValue:@"5"];
    [self.minorFieldCell setStringValue:@"1000"];
    [self.powerFieldCell setStringValue:@"-58"];

    self.isBroadcasting = NO;
    [self.statusField setStringValue:@"Not broadcasting"];



}

-(void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {

    if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {

        self.manager = peripheral;

//        NSUUID *proximityUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"B0702880-A295-A8AB-F734-031A98A512DE"];
//        CMBeaconAdvertismentData *beaconData = [[CMBeaconAdvertismentData alloc] initWithProximityUUID:proximityUUID major:5 minor:5000 measuredPower:-58];
//        [peripheral startAdvertising:beaconData.beaconAdvertisement];

    }
}

-(IBAction)didTapToggleButton:(id)sender {

    if (self.manager && !self.isBroadcasting) {

        NSUUID *proxUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:self.uuidFieldCell.stringValue];
        NSInteger major = [self.majorFieldCell.stringValue integerValue];
        NSInteger minor = [self.minorFieldCell.stringValue integerValue];
        NSInteger power = [self.powerFieldCell.stringValue integerValue];

        CMBeaconAdvertismentData *beaconData = [[CMBeaconAdvertismentData alloc] initWithProximityUUID:proxUUID
                                                                                                 major:major
                                                                                                 minor:minor
                                                                                         measuredPower:power];

        [self.manager startAdvertising:beaconData.beaconAdvertisement];
        self.isBroadcasting = YES;

        [self.statusField setStringValue:@"Broadcasting"];
        [self.toggleButton setTitle:@"Stop broadcasting"];

        [self.uuidFieldCell setEditable:NO];
        [self.uuidFieldCell setTextColor:[NSColor lightGrayColor]];
        [self.majorFieldCell setEditable:NO];
        [self.majorFieldCell setTextColor:[NSColor lightGrayColor]];
        [self.minorFieldCell setEditable:NO];
        [self.minorFieldCell setTextColor:[NSColor lightGrayColor]];
        [self.powerFieldCell setEditable:NO];
        [self.powerFieldCell setTextColor:[NSColor lightGrayColor]];

    } else if (self.manager && self.isBroadcasting) {

        [self.manager stopAdvertising];
        [self.statusField setStringValue:@"Not broadcasting"];

        self.isBroadcasting = NO;
        [self.toggleButton setTitle:@"Start broadcasting"];

        [self.uuidFieldCell setEditable:YES];
        [self.uuidFieldCell setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
        [self.majorFieldCell setEditable:YES];
        [self.majorFieldCell setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
        [self.minorFieldCell setEditable:YES];
        [self.minorFieldCell setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
        [self.powerFieldCell setEditable:YES];
        [self.powerFieldCell setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an external Bluetooth dongle? You need one to be able to advertise iBeacon packets on Yosemite.

From the README of the iBeaconSwiftOSX project you mentioned:

> Note: Despite to the fact that many forums are saying that you cannot use Yosemite as an iBeacon, I can confirm that this solution is working but only with external Bluetooth dongle. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27542365/3824765.

More info in the other Stack Overflow thread, mentioned in the note above:
[CBPeripheralManager startAdvertising not working on OS X yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492316/cbperipheralmanager-startadvertising-not-working-on-os-x-yosemite/27542365#27542365)

Comment: this isn't true. I used MacBeacon by radius to advertise a lot on 10.10

Comment: No i am not using any external bluetooth dongle. so i have mentioned BLE is also supported. on my mac.

Comment: @Daij-Djan, with the built-in Bluetooth? What Mac device? Both Radius on their MacBeacon page (http://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/macbeacon) and the author of the iBeaconSwiftOSX tool, as well as 3 other users in the SO thread I've linked to, state that these don't work on Yosemite with the built-in Bluetooth. Unless Daij-Djan can share some trick on how to make it work, I think you will need to find an external BLE dongle.

Comment: No Trick. Started. Woeks ;) maybe it depends on the Chipset?! Or im going Crazy - can be can be